# Lists all domains hosted on an IP address

Tags: macos, unix, domain, ip, whois

I am looking for a command line way to find all the domains hosted on the same IP address.
Is there a way to scan all A records with nslookup?

How do Sites like: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/web-sites-on-web-server/ do this?

Thanks
C

Comment: Scan *all* A records? Across all 100,000,000 domains? That might take a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not done by an exact lookup...

From [here](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/web-sites-on-web-server/):

> Data is gathered from search engine results, which are not guaranteed to be complete.

Check [here](http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/267) for a few methods on how to do it from the command line.

Comment: robtex does this as well, and it's show up new sites that haven't been indexed yet.

Comment: @dentrasi Some information is gleaned from whois as well, which can also give you answers to queries like "what other domains do they own?"

Comment: Sadly, the link is no longer active.